# Identify button pop-up window no longer displays in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arccatalog

When I use the identify tool within ArcCatalog (10.2.1), I no longer get the pop-up window that provides the information about whatever feature was clicked. I'm not sure when this issue started, but at least the identify tool still does work as expected in ArcMap.

How can I get the pop-up window back in ArcCatalog?

Comment: Wonder if it has just been moved "off" screen like the very bottom of the catalog window so its not visible.

Comment: [The Identify Results window does not display](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21485) describes a similar bug in older versions of ArcCatalog, not sure any of the solutions will work for 10.2 but I bet it's a similar bug.

Comment: It is almost always on a very screen edge with just 1 pixel in the view area or miniscule.  Hunt for it.